# Does FusionAuth provide a single signout?

Tags: fusionauth

Can't seem to find anything that makes FusionAuth send a signal to applications to terminate a user's session upon signout.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

FusionAuth provides an API at `/api/logout` that might work. This API will revoke any refresh tokens that the user has. When refresh tokens are revoked, FusionAuth will send an event out to any configured Webhooks.

Here is the documentation on this API, Webhooks and the event that is fired:

- https://fusionauth.io/docs/v1/tech/apis/login#logout-a-user
- https://fusionauth.io/docs/v1/tech/events-webhooks/events#jwt-refresh-token-revoke
- https://fusionauth.io/docs/v1/tech/events-webhooks/writing-a-webhook

Here are the rough steps you can take to get this working:

1. Create a logout endpoint in your application or in a new microservice (`https://example.com/global-logout`)
2. This endpoint calls the `/api/logout` endpoint in FusionAuth
3. Each application that wants to be notified then writes a Webhook and handles the `jwt.refresh-token.revoke` event

You can see an example Webhook in the documentation link about. A Webhook that handles the `jwt.refresh-token.revoke` event might look like this in Node/JavaScript:

```
router.route('/fusionauth-webhook').post((req, res) => {
  const request = req.body;
  if (request.event.type === 'jwt.refresh-token.revoke') {
    // Clean up all the user's stuff here
  }
});
```

Comment: Brian, we know that when a user logs out, their refresh token is revoked, but are refresh tokens ever revoked for reasons that do not indicate the user is being logged out?

Comment: Not usually but you can revoke a refresh token at anytime really. In most cases, there are only 2 reasons to revoke a refresh token:  
1. The user asks you to. This is essentially a user asking you to log them out of an application on a specific device.  
2. You need to because something changed, there was an issue, or you have security concerns.  
  
In either case, it is essentially a logout. One is initiated by them and one is initiated by you.

Comment: @BrianPontarelli, thank you for your answer. That should work fine.